# Highcharts - Maps data structure

Tags: dictionary, highcharts

I am trying to build an array of data returned from a third party API, and display it using the Highcharts map module.

I've done so with the charts module, using line and pie charts both with not much difficulty. Now that I've moved onto maps, I seem to be running into a bit of difficulty. It was quite clear from the examples provided how the data should be structured to be properly read by Highcharts.

When it comes to the maps module, the data structure is not clear at all. How would I structure my data to pass into my Highcharts map???

`[ 'US' , 'United States' , 32 ] , [ 'CA' , 'Canada' , 100 ]`

If I use the provided :

```
 jQuery.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=world-population-density.json&callback=?', function (data) {

            console.log(data);              

            // Initiate the chart
            jQuery('#geo_map').highcharts('Map', {

                title : {
                    text : 'Campaign Link Clicks Around The World'
                },

                mapNavigation: {
                    enabled: true,
                    buttonOptions: {
                        verticalAlign: 'bottom'
                    }
                },

                colorAxis: {
                    min: 1,
                    max: 1000,
                    type: 'logarithmic'
                },

                series : [{
                    data : data,
                    mapData: Highcharts.maps['custom/world'],
                    joinBy: ['iso-a2', 'code'],
                    name: 'Population density',
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            color: '#BADA55'
                        }
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        valueSuffix: '/km²'
                    },

                }],
                credits: {
                    enabled: false
                },
            });
        });
    });
```

It works. But I can't seem to figure out how to pass in my data. I thought it was as simple as

```
[ 'Abbreviation' , 'Name' , Value ] , [ 'Abbreviation' , 'Name' , Value ]
```

but clearly not. The documentation isn't very clear on data structure.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle link ?

Comment: I will attempt too. It's a little different as I'm calling in the data via AJAX so the fiddle will be a little different than my setup, but I will try and get one set up here. Give ma a few.

Comment: Or maybe a sample of the data, the way it is formatted when the request returns

Comment: Well, have you tried to prepare your data in the form like hardcoded (http://jsfiddle.net/WNTvW/1/) ?

Comment: I had not, I hadn't seen that fiddle before. I came across a few others but they were all requesting data via a json request cross domain. I'll take a look at this guy, thanks Sebastian